# Scheme with postfix

Tags: scheme, postfix-notation

Does anyone can help me to deal with the problem?
I tried for many times, but it still has the error information.
This is my code(scheme)
Thanks!!!

```
(define (postfix l s)
  (cond(
        ((null? l)(car s))
        (else (postfix (cdr l) update-s((car s)))))))
(define (update-s x s)
  (cond(((number? x) (cons x s))
        (else (cons (eval '(x (car s) (cadr s))) (scheme-report-environment 5) (cdr(cdr s)))))))
```

And this is the error inform:

```
else: not allowed as an expression in: (else (postfix (cdr l) update-s ((car s) s)))
```

Comment: You have too many and misplaced parentheses.

Comment: the output of __`number?`__ is not a function.

Comment: How can I deal with it? I want the input is (postfix '(1 2 +)) then I can get 3. I tried to fix my code according to Martin's help. But it still can't solved with (postfix '(1 2 +))......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time, don't forget to add a description of your problem (what should this code do?), expected inputs and outputs, and a version of Scheme you use.

You should also use better names for variables (no `l`, `s`, `x`) and describe their meaning and expected type in your question.

If I understand correctly, you were trying to create a calculator which uses reverse Polish/ postfix notation, where:

- `l` is a list of numbers or symbols
- `s` is a stack with results, represented as a list of numbers
- `x` can be a number or symbol representing some function

From `(scheme-report-environment 5)` I guess you use r5rs Scheme.

Now some of your errors:

- you should define `update-s` before function `postfix`
- your [`cond`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%25_idx_108) has some additional parentheses
- if `cond` has only two branches, you should use [`if`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%25_idx_98) instead
- this part `(postfix (cdr l) update-s((car s)))` should be `(postfix (cdr l) (update-s (car l) s)`
- `(cdr(cdr s))` should be `(cddr s)`
- as for `eval`, I understand why it's here, you were trying to get a function from the symbol, but you should be always careful, as it can also evaluate code provided by user. Consider this example: `(postfix '(1 2 (begin (write "foo") +)) '())`. Maybe it could be better to don't expect this input: `'(1 2 +)`, but this: `(list 1 2 +)` and get rid of `eval`.

The whole code:

```
(define (update-s object stack)
  (if (number? object)
      (cons object stack)
      (cons ((eval object (scheme-report-environment 5))
             (car stack) (cadr stack))
            (cddr stack))))

(define (postfix lst stack)
  (if (null? lst)
      (car stack)
      (postfix (cdr lst)
               (update-s (car lst) stack))))
```

Example:

```
> (postfix '(1 2 +) '())
3
```

Solution without `eval` with different input:

```
(define (update-s object stack)
  (if (number? object)
      (cons object stack)
      (cons (object (car stack) (cadr stack))
            (cddr stack))))

(define (postfix lst stack)
  (if (null? lst)
      (car stack)
      (postfix (cdr lst)
               (update-s (car lst) stack))))
```

Example:

```
> (postfix (list 1 2 +) '())
3
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! I have another question. If I want to make the input like (postfix '(1 2 +)), how can I remove the stack out from postfix? Like I need to build another part for stack? (define stack) (define update stack) (define postfix)?

Comment: I tried to add (define (postfix l)
  (postfixhelper l '())), I changed the postfix to postfixheper, then I get the report like this: application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: +

Comment: I'm new to learn the computer coding, I don't know a lot of things about it. Sorry.........