# How can I fix my scheme code to solve the postfix problems?

Tags: scheme, postfix-notation

Here is the code(Helped with https://stackoverflow.com/a/73017526/19567940) :

```
(define (update-s object stack)
  (if (number? object)
      (cons object stack)
      (cons ((eval object (scheme-report-environment 5))
             (car stack) (cadr stack))
            (cddr stack))))
(define (postfixhelp lst stack)
  (if (null? lst)
      (car stack)
      (postfixhelp (cdr lst)
               (update-s (car lst) stack))))
(define (postfix l)
  (postfixhelper l '()))
(postfix '(1 2 +))
```

I wanna to use `(postfix '(1 2 +))` get the answer 3. But when I put it in compiler, I got the error information:

```
*** ERROR: unbound variable: postfixhelper
    While loading "./jdoodle.sc" at line 15
Stack Trace:
_______________________________________
  0  (postfixhelper l '())
        at "./jdoodle.sc":14
Command exited with non-zero status 70
```

Therefore, how can I fix it and solve this problem?

Comment: What part of `unbound variable: postfixhelper` do you not understand?

Comment: You define `postfixhelp`...